# Serialized nested list corrupt at editor reboot (Unity3D)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, serialization

I am trying to serialize a scriptable object that contains a dictionary which I plan to use to build levels for my game. After the object is created and initialized, I save it as an asset that is then attached to a Monobehavior that generates a level dynamically. Since unity can't serialize dictionaries I am using some lists in conjunction with the ISerializationCallbackReceiver interface, to save and load the data contained in the dictionary. This is the scriptable object code

```
public class LevelsDatabase : ScriptableObject, ISerializationCallbackReceiver
{
    public Dictionary<RoomBiome, Dictionary<RoomType, LevelInfoListWrapper>> BiomeDictionaries =
        new Dictionary<RoomBiome, Dictionary<RoomType, LevelInfoListWrapper>>();

    // Serialization variables
    [SerializeField]
    private List<RoomBiome> _biomeDictionariesKeys = new List<RoomBiome>();
    [SerializeField]
    private List<RoomType> _levelInfoListKeys = new List<RoomType>();
    [SerializeField]
    private List<LevelInfoListWrapper> _levelInfoListValues = new List<LevelInfoListWrapper>();

    public void GenerateLevelsDatabase()
    {
        Debug.Log("Generated Database");
        LoadLevelInfo();
    }

    // Database generation code

    public void OnBeforeSerialize()
    {
        try
        {
            _biomeDictionariesKeys.Clear();
            _levelInfoListKeys.Clear();
            _levelInfoListValues.Clear();

            foreach (var biomeDictionary in BiomeDictionaries)
            {
                _biomeDictionariesKeys.Add(biomeDictionary.Key);
            }

            var key = _biomeDictionariesKeys[0];
            foreach (var roomTypeDictionary in BiomeDictionaries[key])
            {
                _levelInfoListKeys.Add(roomTypeDictionary.Key);
            }

            foreach (var biomeKey in _biomeDictionariesKeys)
            {
                foreach (var roomTypeKey in _levelInfoListKeys)
                {
                    var biomeDictionary = BiomeDictionaries[biomeKey];
                    if (!biomeDictionary.ContainsKey(roomTypeKey))
                    {
                        continue;
                    }
                    var levelInfoList = BiomeDictionaries[biomeKey][roomTypeKey];
                    _levelInfoListValues.Add(levelInfoList);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Debug.Log("Something horrible happened");
        }
    }

    public void OnAfterDeserialize()
    {
        BiomeDictionaries.Clear();
        int index = 0;
        foreach (var biomeKey in _biomeDictionariesKeys)
        {
            BiomeDictionaries.Add(biomeKey, new Dictionary<RoomType, LevelInfoListWrapper>());
            foreach (var roomType in _levelInfoListKeys)
            {
                if (index >= _levelInfoListValues.Count)
                {
                    break; 
                }

                // TODO quick fix, replace it when refactoring
                if (roomType != _levelInfoListValues[index].LevelInfoList[0].RoomType)
                {
                    continue;
                }

                BiomeDictionaries[biomeKey].Add(roomType, _levelInfoListValues[index]);
                index ++;
            }
        }
        Debug.Log("Deserialized");
    }
```

RoomBiome and RoomType are enums and LevelInfoListWrapper is a wrapper for a list of LevelInfo objects defined as following:

```
[Serializable]
public class LevelInfoListWrapper
{
    public List<LevelInfo> LevelInfoList = new List<LevelInfo>();
}
```

LevelInfo is a scriptable object that contains data belonging to the rooms to be used in a Level. It is defined as

```
    [Serializable]
public class LevelInfo : ScriptableObject
{
    public RoomType RoomType;
    public RoomBiome RoomBiome;
    public LevelsEnum Level;

    [SerializeField]
    private List<EntryPoint> _levelEntryPoints = new List<EntryPoint>();
    //TODO add breakable spawners and combat triggers Info
    public void AddEntryPoints(IList<EntryPoint> entryPoints)
    {
        _levelEntryPoints.AddRange(entryPoints);
    }

    public List<EntryPoint> GetEntryPoints()
    {
        return _levelEntryPoints;
    }
}
```

LevelInfo has, among its data a list of EntryPoints defined as such:

```
[Serializable]
public class EntryPoint
{
    public string ToLevel;
    public RoomBiome ToBiome;
    public Vector3 Position;
    public int Index;
    public EntryPointPosition PositionInRoom;
}
```

This code works and the serialization/deserialization process is handled correctly when I play and stop the editor. Unfortunately if I quit the editor and restart it, the lists List < LevelInfo > contained in _levelInfoListValues are not correctly deserialized and contain LevelInfo references initialized with the default constructor. I have read a few posts and references but I am running out of ideas on how to make unity serialize correctly a list of LevelInfoWrapper. The idea to ditch completely unity's serialization and use somenthing like xml or Json is tempting but before resorting to that I was wondering if anyone has any suggestion about a possible solution.
Thanks!

Comment: You tittle is "Serialize Nested List".  If you make the dictionary Static it will not be nested and I think it should solve the issue.  Every time you construct the class LevelsDatabase a new dictionary is being created.  I think you only need one dictionary.

Comment: Do you mean making the BiomeDictionaries variable static? I just tried and it does not work, I still have the same behaviour. Also, maybe I haven't explained the problem clearly, but the _biomeDictionariesKeys and _levelInfoListKeys are deserialized correctly. it's _levelInfoListValues that is not deserialized as expected and that is a List < ListInfoWrapper >, which is the nested list the title refers to.

Comment: Don't use "var".  It gives you run time errors when you should be fixing compiler errors.  Change following : var levelInfoList = BiomeDictionaries[biomeKey][roomTypeKey];

Comment: Care to elaborate your answer a bit more? I am afraid I am not following you, sorry :( Why would "var levelInfoList = BiomeDictionaries[biomeKey][roomTypeKey];" prevent correct deserialization?

Comment: var is perfectly fine. Stating the type explicitly won't change a thing. I'd guess that the writer of that comment does not know what var is.

Comment: David if you re so smart then why is there  a run time error?  Putting actual types into code will give compiler error which will make it easier to figure out the real issue.

Comment: @jdweng Read my comment. Read the documentation for var. The compiler figures out the type of the expression on the rhs of the assignment. The type is determined at compile time. For instance, `string s = "foo"` is indistinguishable from `var s = "foo"`. And FWIW the question does not describe there being a runtime error.

Comment: Yes but a person can't.  Var is used way too often when it should be.  It makes the code much easier to understand when the real types are used.  I always use real type whenever possible.  In this case if a real type was used a run time error would not occur.

Comment: @jdweng Can you explain to me the difference between `string s = "foo";` and `var s = "foo"`? Don't you understand that `var` is a compile time construct?

Comment: @jdweng, in this case there is no run time error anyway, that line is in the OnBeforeSerialize() callback and does what it should do, since the values are correctly saved in the list. The data corruption happens when Unity deserializes the data after an editor reboot (but it works correctly when it deserializes if I enter and exit play mode)

Comment: So is the save (serialize) method writing data to xml file different from original version?  If so did you compare the good and bad xml files?

Comment: The serialization is handled by the Unity engine in the background. What I do in the OnBeforeSerialize() is copying the data from the Dictionaries (which Unity can't serialize) to these lists that the engine should be able to serialize/deserialize. I can see the the lists values in the scriptable object's editor inspector and they are correct. When I reboot the editor though, the deserialization fails somehow but I can't understand the reason, since it works fine if I don't reboot the editor.